# Dynamic width of ionic columns with respect to content length

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I have a dynamic ionic 2 grid system

```
<div>
<ion-row>
  <ion-col >
    <ion-card-header class="card-header">
      {{hunt.title}}
    </ion-card-header>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col *ngIf="!hunt.claims.length" >
    <button ion-fab mini class="new-claim">
      <ion-icon name="disc"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are 2 columns in this but one is conditional. I want the title to occupy full space if there are no claims. But have the accommodate the fab button if there are claims.

But with the above setup, the button goes out of visibility outside `div` if title is long. I could add `width-80` to `title` column. But then it would take only 80% space even when claims are not there.

How can I make sure all the contents are visible taking the full space available, incase there is overflow title is overflow is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `class` for 1st `ion-col` conditionally based on `hunt.claims.length`. By that you could take advantage of CSS specificity to re-apply new CSS rule if class present on first `ion-col`.

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col ng-class="{'take-full-width': !hunt.claims.length}">
    <ion-card-header class="card-header">
      {{hunt.title}}
    </ion-card-header>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col *ngIf="!hunt.claims.length" >
    <button ion-fab mini class="new-claim">
      <ion-icon name="disc"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

**CSS**

```
.card-header{
   /* My older CSS for card-header */
}

.take-full-width .card-header{
   /* Change width in specific case */
   width: 100%;
}
```